# Persistant storage Azure container

Tags: azure

I've been struggling in a couple of days now with how to set up persistent storage in a custom docker container deployed on Azure.

Just for the ease, I've used the official Wordpress image in my container and provided the database credentials through environment variables, so far so good. The application is stateless and the data is stored in a separate MySQL service in Azure.

How to handle content files like server logs or uploaded images, those are placed in /var/www/html/wp-content/upload and will be removed if the container gets removed or if restoring a backup snapshot. Is it possible to mount this directory to a host location? Is it possible to mount this directory so it will be accessible through the FTP to the App Service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I realized that it's not possible to mount volumes to a single container app. To mount a volume you must use Docker Compose and mount the volume as in the example below.

Also, make sure you set the application setting `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE` to `TRUE`

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   wordpress:
     image: wordpress
     volumes:
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/site/wwwroot:/var/www/html
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
```

With this, your uploaded files will be persisted and also included in the snapshot backups.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do this and you should read about PV (persistent volume) and PVC (persistent volume claims) which allows mounting volumes onto your cluster.

In your case, you can mount:

1. [Azure Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-dynamic-pv) - basically a managed NFS endpoint mounted on the k8s cluster
2. [Azure Volumes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-disks-dynamic-pv) - basically managed disk volumes mounted on the k8s cluster

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that's only available when running in a k8s cluster, not a single container?

Comment: A container runs in a cluster! Cluster here is a misnomer and you can have a one pod k8s cluster with no replication - though such a deployment is not recommended for a production environment or otherwise

Comment: Ok, could you please provide an example of setting up a single container in an App Service with a mounted drive?

Comment: Containers are set up on another managed service called AKS and not on App Service solutions on Azure. There are lot of academic material available online on getting started with AKS and mounting file system or drives and I would encourage you to read them and come back here if you have q's.

Comment: So then it's not possible to mount drives when running a docker container on an App Service?